# Using multiple compound assignments in a single expression

Tags: java, operator-precedence, compound-assignment

I am preparing for a Java exam and I am trying to understand operator precedence and compound assignment operators in depth. I played around with a few expressions which use compound assignment during the evaluation of an expression. However, I do not fully understand why these give the result that they do.

```
    int a = 3, b = 0;
    b += a *= (a *= (a *= 2));
    // Result: a=54, b=54
```

What I expected:

```
    //innermost expression evaluated first
    //a = a * 2 = 6, so a assigned to 6; 6 returned
    //Then next one is evaluated as:
    //a = a * 6 = 36, so a assigned to 36; 36 returned
    //The outermost expression evaluated as:
    //a = 36 * 36 = 1296
    //Finally, b = b + 1296, so b = 1296.
```

Instead, a = 54 is the answer. So during all three evaluations of "a *= 2", the old value of a is used instead, so the final answer is a = 3 * 3 * 3 * 2 = 54.

However, this expression behaves differently:

```
    int c = 1, d = 0;
    d += (c *= 2) + (c *= 5) + (c += 100);
    // Result: c=110, d=122
```

If here the old value of c was used we would end up with c = 101 and d = 108. Instead, we end up with c = 2 * 5 + 100 = 110; meaning that in each of those evaluations of "c *= ..", the new (updated) value of c was used each time.

Question: why in the first example the original value of a gets used in the compound assignments, but in the second example the updated value of c gets used?

Comment: By the way, first example doesn't need braces, assignments are evaluated from right to left

Comment: This might be good fodder for an exam, and although these side effects can be handy at times they should be used judiciously as they can hide bugs that are hard to find.

Comment: I completely agree, @WJS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [§15.26.2. Compound Assignment Operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se20/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.2):

> At run time, the expression is evaluated in one of two ways.
> [...]
>
> - the value of the left-hand operand is saved and then the right-hand operand is evaluated

This explains the behavior for the first expression.

According to [§15.18. Additive Operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se20/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18):

> The additive operators have the same precedence and are syntactically left-associative (they group left-to-right).

And [§15.7. Evaluation Order](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se20/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.7):

> The Java programming language guarantees that the operands of operators appear to be evaluated in a specific evaluation order, namely, from left to right.

Thus, the second expression is evaluated from left to right and side effects of updating the variables occur in that order.

Answer (score 2):

> *"... why in the first example the original value of a gets used in the compound assignments, but in the second example the updated value of c gets used?"*

For the first example, it's because it's already trying to assign *a*, so any inner assignments would not apply.

```java
a = a * (a * (a * 2))
a = a * (a * (6))
a = a * (3 * (6))
a = 3 * (3 * (6))
a = 3 * (18)
a = 54
```

> *"... So during all three evaluations of "a *= 2", the old value of a is used instead ..."*

Correct.  You are expecting it to do something like this,

```java
((a *= 2) *= a) *= a)
```

For the second example, it is able to assign *c* since they are not part of one assignment.

```java
(c *= 2) + (c *= 5) + (c += 100)
(2) + (c *= 5) + (c += 100)
(2) + (10) + (c += 100)
(2) + (10) + (110)
122
```

Answer (score 1):

`a` doesn't get update early in first example because `a += x` is equivalent to `a = a + x` and `a` as first operand of binary `+` is evaluated *before* second operand thus keeping initial value. And this condition preserves through the chain.